# Split array of objects with some group of keys

Tags: arrays, go, go-interface

I have an example of json as below:

`{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": [{"k1": v1"}, {"k2": "v2"}]}`

Now I need to split it into two objects:

`{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": {"k1": v1"}}` and 
`{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": {"k2": v2"}}`

Basically I want to split the key3 elements keeping all other keys same in the new structure.

My structure is as below:

```
type myType struct {
    key1 string
    key2 string
    key3 []interface{}
}
```

Please let me know how I can achieve that.

With regards,
-M-

Comment: What have you tried? What problem did you encounter?

Answer (score 0):

There is one minor issue with your struct: The properties have to be exported so that values can be unmarshalled into a struct. In addition you have to tag the properties.

If you want to split an instance of `myType` according to its values in `Key3`, you have to do it manually.

Below is working example:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var bytes = []byte(`{"key1": "val1", "key2": "val2", "key3": [{"k1": "v1"}, {"k2": "v2"}]}`)

type myType struct {
    Key1 string        `json:"key1"`
    Key2 string        `json:"key2"`
    Key3 []interface{} `json:"key3"`
}

func (mt myType) Split() []myType {
    res := make([]myType, len(mt.Key3))

    for i, k3 := range mt.Key3 {
        res[i] = myType{Key1: mt.Key1, Key2: mt.Key2, Key3: []interface{}{k3}}
    }

    return res
}

func main() {
    t := &myType{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", t.Split())
}
```